# How can I dynamically unlink a directive in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I don't know if there's a way to handle this in angularjs, but I want to be able to dynamically unlink/link a directive.

For example, I have a link which goes to a user's profile page:

```
<a ui-sref="users({user_id: post.user.id})">{{post.user.username}}</a>: {{post.text}}
```

Which correctly creates a link: href="/users/5"
But if that post is anonymous, then there's no user id for that post, creating a link: href="/users/", which is not what I want.

The only solution I was able to find was the following:

```
<span ng-if="post.user.id">
    <a ui-sref="users({user_id: post.user.id})">{{post.user.username}}</a>: {{post.text}}
</span>
<span ng-if="!post.user.id">
    <a href>{{post.user.username}}</a>: {{post.text}}
</span>
```

Which wouldn't be so bad if I weren't putting all this nonsense throughout my entire application. Is there a way to create a simple directive that does the following:

```
<a ui-sref="({user_id: post.user.id})" unlink="{'ui-sref': !post.user.id}">post.user.username</a>: {{post.text}}
```

And it would link/unlink ui-sref depending on the value of post.user.id? I could try to create a directive that modifies href, but that would be a mess conflicting with ui-sref. Also, an unlink directive would be more extensible because we could effectively use it with any directive. Any ideas?

Comment: You could make your own directive that uses ui-sref as well as the ng-if logic internally... Just give it an attribute for the ui-sref and the unlink.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. It wouldn't work from the unlinking standpoint, but it could create the link. Hmmm, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dus2VixdzhUJtakOs4WR?p=preview

I made a directive that adds a 'click' event listener before `ui-sref`:

- If the expression is evaluated to `false` then `stopImmediatePropagation` is called.
- I use the native `addEventListener` because of [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4833).

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('unlink',function($parse){
  return {
    compile: function (tElm,tAttrs) {
      var fn = $parse(tAttrs.unlink);
      return {
        pre: function (scope,elm){
          elm[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
            if(! fn(scope)) {
              e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a ui-sref="home" unlink="expression"> Click </a>
```

Comment: you're right for the compiling ^^ It's new at me.Thanks for the point.